# 'pkgdown' for multiple packages

Tags: r, documentation, pkgdown

Our group publishes R packages (for internal use) to a CRAN-like repository.  Users have complained (rightly) that the documentation isn't very accessible to them without firing up R and doing `?function_name` interactively.

So I would like to build a website with the documentation for all the versions of the R packages my group has created.

If I do `pkgdown::build_site()` in my package's top-level directory, that creates a nice self-contained tree `docs/` containing HTML files with all the docs for that package.  It even has a prominent version number at the top of every page, which is nice.

Now I'd like to situate that document tree in a larger site, so that a user can browse to the package they're looking for, look at previous versions, etc.  Is that something someone's set up a solution for?

I'm thinking that the `docs/` directory could simply be `rsync`'d to a web server, building the path from info in `DESCRIPTION`, e.g.:

```
Rscript -e 'pkgdown::build_site()'
mkdir -p r-docs/MyPackage        # Replace with real package name
mv docs r-docs/MyPackage/1.3.1   # Replace with real version
rsync -avz r-docs/ example.com:r-docs/
```

But this gets a bit awkward to do repeatedly - is there some support for this use case in `pkgdown` or another similar package (not necessarily tied to `pkgdown`, would use whatever's most appropriate)?

Comment: Why not run this programmatically, or make it part of the build script whenever you update the package?

Comment: The main problem is that it’s not “the package”, it’s dozens of packages from various developers, so they’d all have to get set up with this tooling. Not insurmountable, but probably a recipe for incomplete compliance.

Comment: Could definitely make it part of the build script- interested to know if there’s a better way than just a one-off script here.  I imagine there are other people out there who’d want a website of docs and a shared solution would be nice.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems pretty simple.  If it all gets uploaded to a standardized repository, even more so.  I imagine something like this: For each package in the repository: 1) download package, 2) build documentation, 3) upload docs to a webfolder.  Done.

Comment: @thc - the 2 main problems with that are 1) it doesn't help anyone else but my group, and 2) the upper-level navigation is bad - unless I build something more complicated, it's just the web server's directory indexes, and there are no links out of a package's docs to the upper levels.  It's a very ugly approach overall.